# Facebook Login Invalid Scope

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using Facebook login, and all of a sudden it stopped working saying "Invalid Scope: user_Friends".

I thought this error was because of the upgrade of the Graph API from v1.0 to v2.0 but my SDK is on the version 3.18 which already comes with GraphAPI v2.0

does any one knows what am I doing wrong? Do I need to make any modifications to be compatible with GraphAPI v2.0?

this is my code I ask for permissions

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    originalFrame = menuBG.frame;
    NSLog( @"### running FB sdk version: %@", [FBSettings sdkVersion] );
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        NSLog(@"Is Connected");
        flagFaceCon = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        flagFaceCon = NO;
        NSLog(@"Is NOT Connected");
    }

    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_Friends"];
}
```

[image]

Comment: quick shot: user_friends, not user_Friends?

Comment: btw: what does the title have to do with the question's body?

Comment: vikingosegundo Thats correct! The correct is user_friends. I wonder only now it gave me problem

Comment: Something at facebook's side changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
user_friends
```

not

```
user_Friends
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also get this error if your app is public but it hasn't been app reviewed yet. Though the docs don't make this entirely obvious. It's a bit fine-print and the error message doesn't clue you into that.

Answer (score 0):

I used for scope user_Friends, but the correct is user_friends (Lower case).